# How to set environment variables via env-file

Tags: java, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile based on the spring guide about [docker](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_containerize_it). My application consumes some private data, so I want to pass these parameters through environment variables. When I run a docker container:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t myname/myapplication --env-file=~/env.list
```

it appears that the variables are not set and the application can't see them, what do I do wrong? How to pass these parameters?

`env.list:`

```
ACCOUNT_ID=my_account_id
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=my_secret_password
```

My `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar $APPLICATION_NAME
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
 docker run
```

takes all parameters before the image and the command. If I do

```
docker run -t --env-file=env.list ubuntu sh -c "while true; do echo world; sleep 100 ;done"
```

and then

```
docker exec -it container_id env
```

I get

```
HOSTNAME=195f18677a91
TERM=xterm
ACCOUNT_ID=my_account_id
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=my_secret_password
HOME=/root
```

Try

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file=~/env.list -t myname/myapplication
```

Answer (score 1):

This works very well:

```
cat <<EOF > test.env
MYVAR=test
EOF
docker run -it --env-file test.env busybox env | grep MYVAR
```

That will print as expected:

```
MYVAR=test
```

In your case in your Java application you can access the environment variables via `System.getenv()`.

Comment: Please take a look at my question, I updated it and provided a sample application that represents the problem.

Comment: the parser for `docker run` should be improved